# generate map path from csv addresses or kml/gpx points?

Tags: path, gps, maps, kml, gpx

I have a list of 200 some addresses. I used geocommons to convert these addresses into long/lat coordinates in kml and gpx format. I need to generate a map by connecting all the points to create a path. What would be the best way to do this? Is there a service that automatically does this, or should I dabble into something like the google maps API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need links between the nodes to calculate some kind of path. To get a realistic path for say a car or a person you need a accurate road data. This is normaly something you pay for, at least where I come from, but maybe there some way to get it for free.

If you get the road data it will probably not in wgs84, rather in some local or national system and you probably have to convert your point in to that other coordinate system.

To do the calculations you could use some kind of "GIS-tool" like the Open Source QGIS. I'm not cure if they got a one-click solution for your problem but I believe you can solve it with this tool. There are also well-defined algoritms to solve it by hand, just search for Traveling Salesman Problem.

Regards